# Building a newsletter from python/django

Tags: python, newsletter

I am trying to figure out how to pragmatically build a newsletter in python that can be mailed or printed as either a PDF or html file, or even downloaded from inside a django-app.   I found a couple of packages with a quick Internet search such as illume and 'newsletter' experimental.  But I thought I would ask if anyone had any experience or sound advice with these packages before I spend hours (or perhaps days) entangled in one of these.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: I've used reportlab to generate a newsletter before. It looked lovely! Be warned, it took the best part of a week to get all the tweaks right.

Comment: Nice... I've used reportlab a couple of times.  Didn't realize it could do that.  Would you be willing to share an example?

Comment: Sorry, can't share that code (work) but there are plenty of [examples](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/03/08/a-simple-step-by-step-reportlab-tutorial/) and reportlab has decent docs.